# $\lim {b_n}^{c_n} = e^{\lim c_n (b_n - 1)}$ when $b_n \rightarrow 1$ and $c_n \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

The notes I'm reading say that:

$\lim {b_n}^{c_n} = e^{\lim c_n (b_n - 1)}$ when $b_n \rightarrow 1$ and $c_n \rightarrow \infty$

This is my attempt to prove this fact given that if $a_n \rightarrow \infty$ then $\left( 1  + \frac{1}{a_n} \right)^{a_n} \rightarrow e$.

$$\lim {b_n}^{c_n} = \left( (b_n - 1) \left(1 + \frac{1}{b_n -1} \right) \right)^{c_n}$$

$$= \lim (b_n - 1)^{c_n} {\left(1 + \frac{1}{b_n -1} \right)^{\frac{1}{b_n - 1}}}^{c_n (b_n - 1)}$$

$$= \left( \lim (b_n - 1)^{c_n} \right) e^{\lim c_n (b_n - 1)}$$

So for the statment to be true we should have $\lim (b_n - 1)^{c_n} = 1$, but generally we don't have ${x_n}^{y_n} \rightarrow 1$ with $x_n \rightarrow 0$ and $y_n \rightarrow \infty$, as with $x_n = \frac{1}{n}$ and $y_n = n$.

Comment: $$b_n^{c_{n}}=\Big(1+\frac{c_n(b_n-1)}{c_n}\Big)^{c_n}$$


It is a nice exercise to show that $\lim_n\Big(1+\frac{a_n}{n}\Big)^n=e^a$ whenever $\lim_na_n=a$. Form this you can show that
$\lim_n\Big(1+\frac{A_n}{X_n}\Big)^{X_n}=e^A$ whenever $A_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}A$ and $X_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow}\infty$

Comment: In my approach $b_n - 1$ does not go to $\infty$, I had that part wrong.

Comment: It is $c_n(b_n-1)$ the sequence whose limit, if exists, that tells you what $\lim_nb^{c_n}_n$ is.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} b_n^{c_n} = \lim_{n\to \infty} e^{c_n \ln b_n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} e^{c_n \times (b_n - 1)\times \frac{\ln\left(b_n\right)}{b_n - 1}} = e^{\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} c_n(b_n -1)}$$

since $\lim\limits_{u\to 1} \frac{\ln u}{u-1}= 1$

Answer (score 0):

$$b_n^{c_{n}}=\Big(1+\frac{c_n(b_n-1)}{c_n}\Big)^{c_n}$$

the conclusion will follow from the following:

> Suppose $A_n$ and $X_n$ are real sequences such that  $A_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}A\in\mathbb{R}$ and $X_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow}\infty$. Then
> $\lim_n\Big(1+\frac{A_n}{X_n}\Big)^{X_n}=e^A$.

Notice that $f(x)=\log(1+x)$ is differentiable for $x>-1$ and that
$$1=f'(0)=\lim_{h\rightarrow{0}}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{\log(1+h)}{h}$$

Now, $\Big(1+\frac{A_n}{X_n}\Big)^{X_n}=\exp\Big(X_n \log(1+\frac{A_n}{X_n})\Big)$. Since $\frac{A_n}{X_n}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$,
$$
X_n \log(1+\frac{A_n}{X_n})=A_n\frac{ \log(1+\frac{A_n}{X_n})}{\frac{A_n}{X_n}}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}A \cdot 1
$$

The continuity of the exponential function does the rest.